# Airtable Typescript - import types from DefinitelyTyped library

Tags: typescript, types, airtable

I'm new to Typescript so please forgive my simple question.

Using the Airtable npm library, I want to import the different types into my project. I've imported the [@types/airtable](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/airtable) npm module but I can't seem to import them.

This is my code:

```
import Airtable, { Base } from "airtable";

const base : Base = Airtable.base("xxx");
```

VSCode shows the following error:

```
'Base' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Base'?ts(2749)
```

When I try changing it to `typeof Base` the type shows as `any` so that can't be it.

Comment: just a guess to get it working, try try `import * as Airtable from "airtable"`.

Comment: i know that's how i've used DefinitelyTyped with `moment`.

Comment: if that works, `const base : Airtable.Base` may work also?

Comment: Thanks but I tried that. I also get a `This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.ts(2497)
` error when using `import` instead of `require`, which may be related.

Comment: `const Base : Airtable.Base` gives this error `'Airtable' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.ts(2702)
`

Comment: if you you leave the type off, what does it show in the tooltip for `base`? It should do type inference, if Airtable is showing up as `namespace`, i'd think that `const base = Airtable.base("xxx");` would do type inference.

Comment: mkay. does Airtable need instantiated first before using? `new Airtable()`, etc.?

Comment: You're right. I feel silly now. 
Using `import Airtable from "airtable"` does infer the type as you say. It throws an error in the debugger though because it's not being treated as a module, which was confusing me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ah nice, yw, thx for giving me something to do during boring day at work!

Comment: Feel free to paste your comment as an answer so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you you leave the type off, what does it show in the tooltip for base? It should do type inference, if Airtable is showing up as namespace, i'd think that `const base = Airtable.base("xxx");` would do type inference.